# Cannot delete directory on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, ext4, tomcat

As you can see below the **root** user cannot remove **myapp** directory but can write and delete files in this directory. The filesystem is **ext4**. Is this a filesystem issue? Do you have any ideas on it?

```
root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls -l | grep myapp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Feb 17 14:30 myapp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 17544487 Dec 18 12:59 myapp.war

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# rm -rf myapp
rm: cannot remove 'myapp': Permission denied

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# sudo rm -rf myapp
rm: cannot remove 'myapp': Permission denied

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls -l myapp/
total 0

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# echo "jsdkfjslkdj" > myapp/testfile

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls -l myapp/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Feb 17 14:38 testfile

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls -lh | grep myapp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Feb 17 14:38 myapp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  17M Dec 18 12:59 myapp.war

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls -l myapp/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Feb 17 14:38 testfile

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# rm -rf myapp
rm: cannot remove 'myapp': Permission denied

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls -l myapp/
total 0
root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls -lh | grep myapp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Feb 17 14:39 myapp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  17M Dec 18 12:59 myapp.war
root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps#
```

@Fiximan

```
# ls -l | grep webapps
drwxrwxrwx 9 root root  4096 Jan 27 21:41 webapps
```

@jcbermu
lsattr's output after issuing **# chattr -i examp** command:

```
# lsattr 
-------------e-- ./myapp
-------------e-- ./host-manager
-------------e-- ./myapp.war
-------------e-- ./examples
-------------e-- ./docs
-------------e-- ./examp
-------------e-- ./examp.war
-------------e-- ./ROOT
-------------e-- ./manager
```

**The solution** (edit)

Finally, the root cause of the problem was on the ext4 attributes (not the permissions) of the parent directory.

```
root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat# lsattr | grep webapps
----i--------e-- ./webapps
```

By removing the `i` attribute from `webapps` directory I got able to remove `myapp` directory using `rm -rf` command.

```
root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat# chattr -i webapps

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat# lsattr | grep webapps
-------------e-- ./webapps

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat# cd webapps/

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls
ROOT  docs  examp  examp.war  examples  host-manager  manager  myapp  myapp.war

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls myapp
testdir

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# rm -rf myapp

root@vm4923:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls
ROOT  docs  examp  examp.war  examples  host-manager  manager  myapp.war
```

Thank you guys for your effort!

Comment: what are the permissions for the parent folder `/opt/tomcat/webapps` ?

Comment: @Fiximan

# ls -l | grep webapps

drwxrwxrwx 9 root root  4096 Jan 27 21:41 webapps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To combine [both](https://superuser.com/a/1042033/231052) [answers](https://superuser.com/a/1042041/231052):

check if the **parent directory `webapps`** has the [`i` or `a` attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr) set by

```
lsattr | grep webapps
```

Then, remove them via

```
chattr -i -a webapps
```

Answer (score 3):

Being *root* check the attributes of files issuing the following command:

```
lsattr
```

The output should be like this:

```
-----------------e- ./.thisfolder/.
-----------------e- ./.thisfolder/somefile
```

if you notice and `i` or `a` remove them with:

```
chattr -i [filename]
chattr -a [filename]
```

*chattr* allows in ext2, ext3 and ext4 filesystemsto modify attributes that override ACLs (chmod, chown,setfacl…) giving you a tight control over the files.

The most common attributes are:

- (A) Don't update atime
- (S) synchronous updates
- (a) append only
- (d) no dump
- (i) immutable
- (j) data journalling
- (t) no tail-merging

*lsattr* simply list those attributes.

Comment: @funk You have an `i` on **examp**

Comment: I updated the initial post. The problem still remains after issuing chattr -i examp command.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misbelief  that to remove directory /a/b/c one has to have the write permission on /a/b/c.
Having that right grants you to manipulate the CONTENT of /a/b/c that is to write/modify/delete files under it.

Hence, to remove /a/b/c you must have the write flag on /a/b

Comment: Unless you're *root*, in which case the basic permissions are ignored.

Comment: True. Shame on me for missing the id in the question.